# ¿Cuándo se utiliza 'creía' en el mismo sentido como 'supongo'?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática

Mi amigo de España me escribió la siguiente frase:

*El código, con el que haces las prácticas, es tan fácil de leer que de escribir. **Creía** que despues de pasar el exámen para entrar en el trabajo sería pan comido.*

Cuando le pregunté por qué se utilizó 'creía', me respondió: es como 'I guess'.

Si eso es verdad, ¿Cuándo y en qué contextos se utiliza así?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo pienso que en esa frase, el verbo *`creer`* tiene el sentido de *`suponer`* o *`dar por sentado`*. De hecho, creo que el verbo *`suponer`* podría ser incluso más apropiado para este caso. Por lo tanto, pienso que traducirlo usando el verbo *`guess`* es perfectamente válido, aunque debería ser en pasado (*`guessed`*).

Si nos fijamos en las definiciones del diccionario de la R.A.E., podemos ver que uno de los significados de `creer` y `suponer` es muy similar:

> **[Creer](http://dle.rae.es/creer)**: *Tener algo por verosímil o probable*.
>   
>   **[Suponer](http://dle.rae.es/suponer)**: *Dar por sentado y existente algo.*

Algunos ejemplos en los que `creer` y `suponer` son intercambiables:

> Creo/Supongo que vendrá a la fiesta de mañana.
>   
>   Creía/Suponía que el trabajo estaría terminado hoy.

Ejemplos en los que **no** son intercambiables:

> ¿Crees en Jesucristo?
>   
>   No pude creerlo hasta que lo vi con mis propios ojos.
>   
>   Es tan ingenua que cree todo lo que le dicen.

---

Por cierto, hay un error en la frase anterior, que debería ser:

> ... es tan fácil de leer ***como*** de escribir.

Answer (score 0):

Sería en realidad un `"I thought"`

> El código, con el que haces las prácticas, es tan fácil de leer que de escribir. Pensé que después de pasar el exámen para entrar en el trabajo sería pan comido.

Comment: creo que sería "pensaba".

Comment: creo que ambos funcionan bien no? @WalterMitty

Comment: No sé.  "creía" es imperfecto mientras "pensé" es pretérito.